# Angular doesn't see or read ngx-file-drop library

Tags: angular

I always get this error when starting my application in ngx-file-drop. But even though ngx-file-drop is in nodemodule, it always gives this error.

```
Error: src/app/services/common/file-upload/file-upload.component.html:2:5 - error NG8001: 'ngx-file-drop' is not a known element:
1. If 'ngx-file-drop' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ngx-file-drop' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

2     <ngx-file-drop dropZoneLabel="Drop files here" [accept]="options.accept" (onFileDrop)="selectedFiles($event)">
      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/services/common/file-upload/file-upload.component.ts:10:16
    10   templateUrl: './file-upload.component.html',
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component FileUploadComponent.


Error: src/app/services/common/file-upload/file-upload.component.html:2:52 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'accept' since it isn't a known property of 'ngx-file-drop'.
1. If 'ngx-file-drop' is an Angular component and it has 'accept' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ngx-file-drop' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.

2     <ngx-file-drop dropZoneLabel="Drop files here" [accept]="options.accept" (onFileDrop)="selectedFiles($event)">
                                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/services/common/file-upload/file-upload.component.ts:10:16
    10   templateUrl: './file-upload.component.html',
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component FileUploadComponent.


Error: src/app/services/common/file-upload/file-upload.component.html:2:106 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'Event' is not assignable to parameter of type 'NgxFileDropEntry[]'.
  Type 'Event' is missing the following properties from type 'NgxFileDropEntry[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 29 more.

2     <ngx-file-drop dropZoneLabel="Drop files here" [accept]="options.accept" (onFileDrop)="selectedFiles($event)">
                                                                                                           ~~~~~~

  src/app/services/common/file-upload/file-upload.component.ts:10:16
    10   templateUrl: './file-upload.component.html',
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component FileUploadComponent.




× Failed to compile.
```

FileUpload Html

```
<div class="center">
    <ngx-file-drop dropZoneLabel="Drop files here" [accept]="options.accept" (onFileDrop)="selectedFiles($event)">
        <ng-template ngx-file-drop-content-tmp let-openFileSelector="openFileSelector">
            {{options.explanation}}
            <button type="button" (click)="openFileSelector()">Seç</button>
        </ng-template>
    </ngx-file-drop>
    <div class="upload-table" *ngIf="files">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Seçilenler</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="upload-name-style">
                <tr *ngFor="let item of files; let i=index">
                    <td><strong>{{ item.relativePath }}</strong></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

FileUploadModule.TS

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FileUploadComponent } from './file-upload.component';
import { NgxFileDropModule } from 'ngx-file-drop';






@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    FileUploadComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FileUploadModule,
    NgxFileDropModule,

  ],
  exports:[
    FileUploadComponent
  ]
})
export class FileUploadModule { }
```

AppModule.TS

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AdminModule } from './admin/admin.module';
import { UiModule } from './ui/ui.module';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { ToastrModule } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { NgxSpinnerModule } from 'ngx-spinner';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { DeleteDirective } from './directives/admin/delete.directive';
import { DeleteDialogComponent } from './dialogs/delete-dialog/delete-dialog.component';




@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
    
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    AdminModule, UiModule, BrowserAnimationsModule,
    ToastrModule.forRoot(),
    NgxSpinnerModule,
    HttpClientModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: "baseUrl", useValue: "https://localhost:7035/api", multi : true}
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Solutions I tried:
Updating Angular (I created a new nodemodule with the versions I got from the old package.json as this breaks it more)

I have deleted the ngx-file-drop library many times and installed it with npm but with no results.

I can't open my project right now. I am waiting for your answers.

Comment: Your example works fine for me. Could you share a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) using stackblitz for example ?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oawpsh?file=src/file-upload/file-upload.component.html here it is. Maybe i did it wrong but i did it by adding the part where i got the error.

Comment: Should i use older versions?

Comment: @prawlercode the stackblitz is not properly set up, the module is unused. After fixing this I'm getting an error `Cannot find module 'ngx-spinner' or its corresponding type declarations.`

Comment: I don't know how to use stackblitz is there anything i can do to solve problem?

Comment: Can you try this one? https://stackblitz.com/edit/how-to-use-gpvuxr?file=index.html

Comment: I forked your stackblitz, fixed the import errors and it works fine too : [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xkecvv?file=src/app.module.ts)

Comment: Should i just copy app file to my application? Because there are a lot of files that i didn't add

Comment: Try to remove your app's features one by one to see if your issue persists. If it does, compare the stackblitz's imports with your own to check if you missed something